# How to get a reference to a string in Scala and modify the original string by modifying this reference?

Tags: scala, reference, value-type

As I understand, strings in Scala are value types:

```
var a = "hello"
var b = a
b = "hi"
```

-

```
println(a)   // hello
println(b)  // hi
```

I want a to point to b and make code above print

```
hi
hi
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The title of your question is confused. Modifying references is separate from modifying values. Furthermore, Scala uses Java's `String` and they are immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Warning: This is very bad functional style*

Your `a` and `b` are strings. What you want is a **reference** to a string!

```
class StringRef(var s:String)  

val a = new StringRef("hello")
val b = a
b.s = "Hi"
println(a.s)   // Hi
println(b.s)   // Hi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because in [Java/Scala everything is assigned-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776145/how-can-java-assignment-be-made-to-point-to-an-object-instead-of-making-a-copy).  You can't assign a variable to directly reference another variable.

Instead you can assign both variables to contain the same reference value to a mutable object.