# Why did the array elements change in this code example?

Tags: java, arrays

I started to learn JAVA and am trying to understand something about arrays. So within the code below, the elements of `arr1` has been assigned to `arr2[1]` and in the second loop, `arr2[row][col]` was incremented.

I was just monkeying around with debugger and realized that the content of `arr1` has also been incremented along with `arr2[row][col]`.

It might be a dummy question but I really could not understand it, can you elaborate the logic there please?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[][] arr2 = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
    arr2[1] = arr1;
    for (int row = 0; row < arr2.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr2[row].length; col++){
            System.out.print( arr2[row][col] + " " );
            arr2[row][col]++;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 1):

**arr2[1] is a reference to arr1**
So, when you increment a number in arr2[1], it also reflects in arr1.

Java object variables are references, so arr2[1] simply points to the same address as arr1.
You can find many articles on this:

- [how-can-java-assignment-be-made-to-point-to-an-object-instead-of-making-a-copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776145/how-can-java-assignment-be-made-to-point-to-an-object-instead-of-making-a-copy)
- [Java assign reference](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-assigning-object-reference/)

Your code, **declares an array**:

```
int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

**declares an multidimensional array (array of array):**

```
int[][] arr2 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

**assigns the arr2's second array (ie: arr2[1]) to arr1**:

```
arr2[1] = arr1; // {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: I definitely got that part. My question is, why all the elements of `arr1` get incremented as the program executes `arr2[row][col]++;` each time?

Comment: see my edit, I think the answer is there now (the very first line)

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[][] arr2 = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
arr2[1] = arr1;
```

you are changing the 2nd element of arr2 for the the value of arr1
so

```
arr2 = { {1, 2, 3}, { 1, 2, 3, 4}, {7, 8, 9} };
```

is correct!

***and in the second loop, arr2[row][col] was incremented.***

yes you increment those, but the result of that operation is not getting assigned to anything so, those changes are getting lost...

Answer (score 0):

You are setting *arr2[1]* **referencing** the variable *arr1*. So, when you modify *arr2[1]* you are modifying the value of *arr1* really.

If you want to set to arr2[1] the value of arr1, use this:

```
arr2[1] = arr1.clone();
```

The method clone returns a **value**, not a reference.

Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: Er, not quite.  `clone()` returns a reference to a copy of the value.